# Saving a file in Cordova on iOS not working - fine in Android

Tags: ios, file, cordova

I have a cordova app where i'm downloading a pdf file, saving it locally and then opening it.
It works fine in Android but iOS gives a message in the output window that its written the file but cant open a file of null.

Originally I was using cordova.file.externalRootDirectory which worked in Android but not iOS.
I changed this to cordova.file.dataDirectory which again working in Android but not iOS.

According to searches I've done, using cordova.file.dataDirectory should work on both platforms.

I've tried adding

to the config file, but this makes no difference.

```
var contentType = "application/pdf";
var folderpath = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
var filename = filedate + ".pdf";

savebase64AsPDF(folderpath,filename,data,contentType)


function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

    var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

  var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
  return blob;
}

function savebase64AsPDF(folderpath,filename,content,contentType){
// Convert the base64 string in a Blob
var DataBlob = b64toBlob(content,contentType);

console.log("Starting to write the file :3");

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(folderpath, function(dir) {
    console.log("Access to the directory granted succesfully");
    dir.getFile(filename, {create:true}, function(file) {
        console.log("File created succesfully.");
        file.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
            console.log("Writing content to file");
            fileWriter.write(DataBlob);
            console.log("Finished writing file.");
            //open file
            cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(folderpath + filename, 'application/pdf');
        }, function(){
            alert('Unable to save file in path '+ folderpath);
        });
    });
});
}
```

The expected (and desired) result is what happens on Android in that the file is saved locally and then opened in the default pdf reader.

The best I can get from iOS is a message in the output window of xcode that says it has "Finished writing file" and then another line stating that "looking for file at (null)"

No exceptions or errors, just nothing.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: What version of Cordova and your plugins (File, File Opener 2, etc.) are you using?

Comment: Seems to me the problem could be FileOpener2 itself, and so two things: 1) it says it has issues with cordova 6.x, 2) you could use its built in error handler to log what's going on, maybe (see https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2#quick-examples).

Comment: I have Cordova v 9.0.0, FileOpener2 v 2.2.0, File v 6.0.1
Thanks for the replies, I'll have a look at the link you posted now.

Comment: Have just checked the mac and it's running cordova 8.1.0 and wont update for some reason.
Going to try building it on the laptop and then run it on the mac to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: The plugin apparently has trouble with spaces and special characters -- https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2/issues/190, https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2/issues/14 -- and may need different ways to encode for ios/android. Knowing what error you receive and a sample file name (i don't see `filedate` defined above) may help pinpoint.

Comment: Thank you for that....it could well be a space. The filename is in the format of:
12345678-March 2019.pdf
I'll change that and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: It would seem that the space was the issue. Thank you so much for the help. hugely appreciated.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Can you mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin fileOpener2 has a [known issue with spaces in the filename for iOS](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2/issues/14). You can [reportedly use](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2/issues/14#issuecomment-68037022) `decodeURIComponent` to display files affected by this, e.g., in this case:

```js
var docUrl = folderpath + filename;

if ( device.platform.toLowerCase() === 'ios' ) { // only change for iOS
  docUrl = decodeURIComponent( docUrl );
}

cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(docUrl, 'application/pdf');
```

You can also simply remove/replace the spaces when saving.

(This plugin also has issues with [non-ASCII characters](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2/issues/190). Solutions here can [get a little complex](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2/issues/190#issuecomment-358985029).)